# Is the source code for the Entity Framework Power Tools extension available? If not, will it ever be?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, performance, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I've encountered some performance problems when using the [EF Power Tools extension beta 2](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d) to reverse-engineer my complex database. I had some theories as to how I can improve this, but couldn't find any reference to published source.

Will this extension ever be released as open source? If yes, when and where?

---

By the way, the problem I'm having is that the reverse-engineering takes a very long time on my complex database with hundreds of entities (during which the SQL Server is working) and hangs the Visual Studio UI (I'm using 2010).

The process takes about 10 minutes on my beefy workstation and absolutely idle SQL Server.
I tried it on a much simpler DB before and it finished in about 5 seconds.

I'm guessing it's creating a very heavy schema query on the DB, and then hangs the UI thread while waiting for the response. If that's the case, I'd try to split the query results and fetch data in chunks, and also perhaps move the generation code into a separate thread while the UI gives feedback on the progress.

A simpler solution would be to just create a command-line interface to do the same thing (is there one already and I'm missing it?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is available on Entity Framework code base [here](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/42370a831b55)

[image]

Fork it, contribute, do what you want.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like it was added to that CodePlex project a week after I asked my question. It's been a while so I hope I'll remember what I wanted to fix...